# SVG text element not showing in android browser

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to embed a svg graphics into my page using the javascript code below, but when I look at the webpage with the android's default browser named 'Internet' version 5.8 on my phone, the circle is showing, but the text is not showing up. It works fine on other browsers, but I have a concern that it might not be showing up on some of the safari browsers either. What am I doing wrong here? Note that when I copy and paste the output svg code into my source file and open it, the text will show up, so I am pretty sure that there are some problem with the javascript.

```
var svgtag=document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','svg');
svgtag.setAttribute('height','500');
svgtag.setAttribute('width','500');
document.getElementById("piechart").appendChild(svgtag);

var circle=document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','circle');
circle.setAttribute('cx','250');
circle.setAttribute('cy','250');
circle.setAttribute('r','200');
circle.setAttribute('fill','#999');
svgtag.appendChild(circle);

var sample=document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','text');
sample.setAttribute('x','250');
sample.setAttribute('y','250');
sample.setAttribute('font-size','12');
sample.setAttribute('fill','#000');
sample.innerHTML='someting';
svgtag.appendChild(sample);
```

Comment: Using createTextNode instead of innerHTML worked!! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to create a text node is via

```
text = document.createTextNode("someting");
sample.appendChild(text);
```

instead of the innerHTML

This should work on Android's default browser, and will also work everywhere else too.